# BIOS System Firmware failed

Tags: central-processing-unit, bios

One of my company's servers won't boot. Both CPUs' error LEDs are lit. The iRMC interface shows the following errors:

```
CPU 1 failed
CPU 2 failed
BIOS System Firmware (BIOS/EFI) failed
```

All other entries are OK. I'm confused because the server ran fine until we re-booted it after installing Windows updates; then first the RAID system reported that it couldn't find any hard drives, the next boot 1 of 2 CPUs was reported non-operational, and on subsequent boots both CPUs are non-operational. That's why I had a look at the iRMC; maybe the "BIOS..." line hints towards the root of the issue?

The server is a PRIMERGY TX200 S4 with two 2.0 GHz XEON E5405 CPUs. The OS is Windows Server 2003 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not at all familiar with Fujitsu servers; if this were a Dell/HP/IBM, I'd ask if you'd read the manual and contacted support.

This sounds pretty simple though - if the BIOS has failed (corrupted code or failed hardware), the server is hosed until it gets fixed. Does this unit have a redundant ROM that you could select at POST?

Comment: I don't think it has one. I've tried to run a BIOS update over USB, but couldn't because the device wasn't listed in the boot manager.